# How do I add css to ionic 2 component template

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

I want to add css to this code, but I don't want to do it inline.
when I change it in the scss class it doesn't seem to be applied on the elements.

this is the html

```
<ion-content #popoverContent  class="popover-page">

<div id="map" #popoverText ></div>
```

this is the popovercontent in the .ts file

```
@Component({
template :`
<ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>Ionic</ion-list-header>
    <button ion-item (click)="close()">Learn Ionic</button>
    <button ion-item (click)="close()">Documentation</button>
    <button ion-item (click)="close()">Showcase</button>
    <button ion-item (click)="close()">GitHub Repo</button>
</ion-list>`
})

export class PopoverPage {
constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

close() {
this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
}
```

So when I change this in the .scss file it doesn't do anything

```
ion-list-header {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I really don't want to add inline css, anyone an idea on how to fix it?

Comment: In my ionic 2 app, there is `app.core.scss` file in `theme` folder. Here you need to import all the `.scss` files. Could you check if it is included. If it is, could you inspect the element and check where `background-color` is taking preference? Please reply with your findings. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give id in any parent tag.

```
@Component({
template :`
<ion-list id="il1">
    <ion-list-header>Ionic</ion-list-header>
    <button ion-item (click)="close()">Learn Ionic</button>
    <button ion-item (click)="close()">Documentation</button>
    <button ion-item (click)="close()">Showcase</button>
    <button ion-item (click)="close()">GitHub Repo</button>
</ion-list>`
})
```

Then add in scss.

```
#il1{
  ion-list-header {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

This will take preference.

Comment: it works for me in my project. try to see in inspect/firebug which css is overwriting it. add !important if it's only necessary. and make sure you are not putting above css inside any other classes.